# Writing to a collection in MongoDB Atlas with JS server code

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, mongodb-atlas

I need to rebuild the JS (server) code to write to a DB collection in MongoDB Atlas.

Since I am encountering some problems on the way, I decided to write this post and see if someone could give me some help by having a new look at it.

First, here is how the collection looks:

```
_id: 6501df383452b6a687eb89c6
channelID: "ENR6318ahecz"
voiceRecordID: "6501df352839b6a687eb89c4"
timeStamp: 1694676496005

_id: 6501df783439b6a687da89ca
channelID: "ENR6318ahecz"
voiceRecordID: "6501df712219b6a687eb89c8"
timeStamp: 1691921560338

.....
```

I have this scheme working in TypeScript code, to access (by reading) the collection:

```
    const speakSchema = new Schema({
        channelID: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        voiceRecordID: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        timeStamp: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    })

    interface SpeakDoc extends Document {
        channelID: string
        voiceRecordID: string
        timeStamp: number
    }

    interface SpeakModel extends Model<SpeakDoc> {}

    const theModel = (models && models.Voice) ? (models.Voice as SpeakModel) :
                                            mongoose.model<SpeakDoc, SpeakModel>
                                                    ('Voice',speakSchema,'mycollection')
```

Then I have code like the one below to read the collection:

```
    await connectMDB()

    try {
        const theResult = await theModel
        .find({channelID:channel})
        return theResult
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in Read-Function:", error);
        throw error; // Rethrow the error to propagate it.
    }
```

All the above works perfectly for now.

Next comes the problem. I need to be able to insert new records in the collection using JS. The code is in express server.

Here is what I have at this point, but it is not working:

```
    ....
    const {Schema,model} = mongoose;

    const vxSchema = new Schema({
      channelID: String,
      voiceRecordID: String,
      timeStamp: Number
    },
    {
        versionKey: false 
        /* This gets rid of the "__v: 0" that is
        otherwise added to the collection. */
    });

    const VxIns = model('VxIns', vxSchema);

    .....

    function saveAudioToGridFS(audioBlob) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const gridFSBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db),
                        upldName = getAudioName()

            const writeStream = gridFSBucket.openUploadStream(upldName);

            writeStream.on('close', (file) => {
                if (file !== undefined) {
                    resolve(file._id); // Return the GridFS file ID
                }
            });

            writeStream.on('finish', (file) => {
                if (file !== undefined) {
                    resolve(file._id); // Return the GridFS file ID
                }
            });

            writeStream.on('error', (error) => {
                reject(error);
            });

        // Convert the Blob into a readable stream using streamifier
        const readableStream = streamifier.createReadStream(audioBlob);
        // audioBlob.pipe(writeStream);
        readableStream.pipe(writeStream);
        });
    } /* End of saveAudioToGridFS */


    server.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            if (!req.body.audio) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No audio data uploaded.' });
            }

            console.log("Before saveAudioToGridFS")
            const audioBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body.audio, 'base64'),
                        fileId = await saveAudioToGridFS(audioBuffer);
            console.log("fileId=",fileId)

            // Create a new VX object:
            const newRcd = new VxIns({
                channelID:req.body.channel,
                voiceRecordID:fileId,
                timeStamp: new Date().getTime()
            });
        
            // Insert the newRcd in our MongoDB database
            await newRcd.save();
            res.json({ fileId });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({
                message: 'An error occurred during upload.',
                error: JSON.stringify(error)
            });
        }
    });
```

Can someone see at a glance what is, or what could be, wrong in this last chunk of code ? Knowing that the first presented TypeScript code is working.

P.S. I just noticed that the call to saveAudioToGridFS, while saving data in the database as expected does not return the fileId as it should.

Comment: Is `server.post('/upload'` returning an error i.e is control flow throwing to the `catch(error)` block or is `res.json({ fileId });` coming back just not saving?

Comment: @jQueeny. The control flow is not throwing to the catch(error) block. I noticed something was wrong when saving the data in GridFS. I just edited the post adding the code for saveAudioToGridFS(). It is weird, because this code has been working at some point, so I must surely be missing something.